# SQL server - order by group after you find highest count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

How do I order second column based on primary sorted. Lets say...

```
select Customer, Status, count(*) as Qty
from Inventory
group by Customer, Status
order by count(*) desc
```

returns

```
Customer   |  Status  |  Qty
-------------------------------
102        |  2       |  500
101        |  1       |  400
102        |  1       |  300
101        |  2       |  200
102        |  3       |  100
```

How can I group customer together after the Qty is sorted? I want Qty to be my primary sort and Customer to be secondary.

```
Customer   |  Status  |  Qty
-------------------------------
102        |  2       |  500
102        |  1       |  300
102        |  3       |  100
101        |  1       |  400
101        |  2       |  200
```

Thanks!

EDIT: forgot desc after count(*)

Comment: You can order by multiple fields.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen the problem is if I do 'order by count(*), Customer' then it does nothing since Qty take priority. But if I do 'order by Customer, count(*)' then Customer would list like I want but highest qty wouldn't be on top. I feel like I saw a way to order and group together but I just can't find it.

Comment: Try with `3` instead of `count(*)` in the `order by count(*) desc`

Comment: @Tek my updated answer will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mister Positive answer didn't work out for some reason but gave me the lead.
I used cte and add the max count partition and it works for my intent

Based on example in question, cte would return something like this.

```
Customer   |  Status  |  Qty  |  mx
-------------------------------------
102        |  2       |  500  |  500
101        |  1       |  400  |  400
102        |  1       |  300  |  500
101        |  2       |  200  |  400
102        |  3       |  100  |  500
```

Query:

```
with cte as (
  select Customer
       , Status
       , count(*) as Qty
       , max(count(*)) over (partition by Customer) as mx
  from Inventory
  group by Customer, Status
)
select Customer, Status, Qty
from cte
order by mx desc, Qty desc
```

Feel pretty dirty to me but this will work for now.
Thanks all.

Comment: Glad it was of use @Tek

Comment: you should up vote any answers that were of help to get to the final solution @Tek. I should have thought of CTE. :-/

Comment: @MisterPositive Haha I want to upvote you but I don't even have 15 reputations lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

```
Create Table #MyTempTable ( Customer int, MyStatus int, Qty Int)

Insert Into #MyTempTable
Select Customer, Status, count(*)
from Inventory
group by Customer, Status

Select * from #MyTempTable Order by Qty DESC, Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into how efficient this is but window functions provide the solution to this problem...

```
SELECT    customer, status, COUNT(*)
FROM      Inventory AS I
GROUP BY  customer, status
ORDER BY  SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY customer) DESC,
          COUNT(*) DESC
;
```

Here's the code to create and populate the `Inventory` table:

```
CREATE
TABLE   Inventory
(
  customer  int   not null,
  status    int   not null
);

INSERT
INTO    Inventory
VALUES  (101, 1), (101, 1), (101, 1), (101, 1),
        (101, 2), (101, 2),
        (102, 1), (102, 1), (102, 1),
        (102, 2), (102, 2), (102, 2), (102, 2), (102, 2),
        (102, 3)
;
```